# If $n$ be a proper divisor of $a=|C_a|$ then what should be closed form of $\sum\limits_{d|n}\eta_d(C_a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

can some one help me to find out this ?

Let us denote the number of elements of order $d$ in a group $G$ by $\eta_d(G)$. Assume that $C_a$ be a cyclic group of order $a$ and $n$ be a particular divisor of $a$.

We are willing to find out $$\sum\limits_{d|n}\eta_d(C_a)$$
In other words, for each divisor $d$ of $n$ when $n$ is a fixed divisor of the order of a cyclic group $C_a$ of order $a$, we need to find the find the number of elements of order $d$ and then sum up them.

Well, if $n=a$ then the number is $\sum\limits_{d|a}\varphi(d)$ which is $a$ itself.

But what about $n$ is proper divisor of $a$ ?

Can we find any closed formula?

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found it. Please someone suggest me if I am making any mistake.

Given that $C_a$ is cyclic group of order $a$. Let $C_a=\langle r\rangle$ where $|r|=a$. Now $n$ is a proper divisor of $a$. which mean we are actually entering in to the subgroup of order $n$.

Since fundamental theorem of cyclic group [Refer: Contemporary  Abstract Algebra by Gallian] says that any subgroup finite cyclic group is cyclic and is unique of its order, so it follows that we are actually entering in to the cyclic subgroup of $C_a$ of order $n$ ( this is unique subgroup ).

Moreover, $d$ run over all the divisor of $n$. hence the value is 
$$\sum\limits_{d|n}\varphi(d)$$ which is nothing but $n$ itself.

Thus if $n|a$ and $n\leq a$ then $$\sum\limits_{d|n}\eta_d(C_a)=n$$

tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think this is the good argument, in general, I think that $\sum_{d|n}\eta_d(C_a)=gcd(n,a)$.